# Installing SQL Server 2008 32bit on 64bit : WoW64 error

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, 64-bit

Consider a problem installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7 x64. The installer gives some WoW64 error.

Is it possible to install a 32-bit version of SQL Server 2008 on a 64-bit OS like Windows 7 x64?

If so, can you suggest how to get around the WoW64 exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#SE32) the 32-bit version of SQL *is* supported on Windows 7 64-bit.

But you're going to need SQL 2008 with SP1.

If you don't have a piece of SQL media with SP1 already on it then you'll need to make a slipstreamed disk for yourself.  Luckily, in SQL 2008 they added the ability to make a slipstream copy with SP1 in it, and MS provides [instructions here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955392).

You can get the SQL 2008 SP1 installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en).

HTH